# error in inserting image in Webpy

Tags: python, html

I am new at python, I want to insert image in html. First i have tried it with static page concept but `web.reloder` doesn't works. It shows an error after that I have tried following code but still I could not get desired output

```
import web

urls = ('/', 'hello')

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:
    def GET(self):
        return """<html><body><img src="images.jpg"></body></html>"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the `web.reloader` you were talking about, but here's how you generally use static files.

Create the directory `static` where your script runs. Then, put `images.jpg` into `static`.

In your HTML, change your image tag to `<img src="/static/images.jpg`. So web.py knows where to retrieve that image.

So a better visualization of the whole directory now is this:

```
project
   |
   |-- main.py
   |
   |-- static
          |
          |-- images.jpg
```

Okay, since you are rather new, I will let you off but the question you just asked COULD be searched online easily. Just go to Google-fu and search `static files webpy`. And you will get [this](http://webpy.org/cookbook/staticfiles) and [this](http://webpy.org/faq).

Please, at least try to search next time.